# Run Python script at command line - cannot find '__main__' module error

Tags: python-3.x

This is the first time I have ever tried running a python script from the command line.  I type: `python C:\Users\Jonathan\OneDrive - Mazars in Oman\Trading\Systems\FibMatrix\Testing Trade Analysis\Python Codes\CreateDataTablePythonScriptv2.py -a='USDJPY'`

I get this error:  `C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\OneDrive'`

The script trying to run is:

```
import sqlite3
import sys

PairName = sys.argv[1]
DTBLocation = 'C:/Users/Jonathan/OneDrive - Mazars in Oman/Trading/Systems/FibMatrix/Testing Trade Analysis//SQLite/Trade Analysis.db'
connection = sqlite3.connect(DTBLocation)
cursor = connection.cursor()

TableName = PairName+'_DATA'
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}
(
    Date_Time INTEGER,
    Open REAL,
    Max_60m_Box REAL

 )""".format(TableName))
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

I have searched, but was not able to find an answer.  I appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\OneDrive'`

is the hint here

your path contains spaces (and it tried to be parsed up to first space)

try enclosing whole path with quotes

`python "C:\Users\Jonathan\OneDrive - Mazars in Oman\Trading\Systems\FibMatrix\Testing Trade Analysis\Python Codes\CreateDataTablePythonScriptv2.py" -a='USDJPY'`

Comment: Yes, that was it.  I thought it was quoted, but I guess it was not.  Thanks!